# Camera position and device controls using the waves example

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a website where i need to use threejs. I used the waves example in a landing page and it is working well on desktop/laptop.

However, I need to be able to move the waves (same behaviour as mouse in desktop) but with the device gyroscope/accelerometer and it is working using the devicecontrols that i found in another example. The problem is that it is my first time using three and working with 3d and i am lost. The dots are really small they only seem to move in a very small line and i dont know how or where the camera should look.

For example,

- Desired behaviour (https://www.dropbox.com/s/d11srwqww8jtuda/PhoneWanted.png?dl=0)
- Current on desktop (https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3rpcnovrfr2v1x/Desktop.png?dl=0)
- Current on mobile (https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9c1mojgi5zt55y/IMG_2385.jpeg?dl=0)

On mobile should look the same as on desktop and move the waves but only horizontally...

Is this possible?

Mobile Script

```js
<script>
 if (screen && screen.width < 900) {
  //alert("Mobile");
  if ( WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false ) {
    document.body.appendChild( WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage() );
   }
   var SEPARATION = 100, AMOUNTX = 50, AMOUNTY = 50;
   var container;
   var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
   var particles, count = 0;
   var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
   var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
   var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
   init();
   animate();
   function init() {
    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls( camera );
    camera.position.z = 1000;
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //
    var numParticles = AMOUNTX * AMOUNTY;
    var positions = new Float32Array( numParticles * 3 );
    var scales = new Float32Array( numParticles );
    var i = 0, j = 0;
    for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {
     for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {
      positions[ i ] = ix * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTX * SEPARATION ) / 2 ); // x
      positions[ i + 1 ] = 0; // y
      positions[ i + 2 ] = iy * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTY * SEPARATION ) / 2 ); // z
      scales[ j ] = 1;
      i += 3;
      j ++;
     }
    }
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
    geometry.addAttribute( 'scale', new THREE.BufferAttribute( scales, 1 ) );
    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
     uniforms: {
      color: { value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
     },
     vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
     fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent
    } );
    particles = new THREE.Points( geometry, material );
    scene.add( particles );
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
   }

            function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
   }
   function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
   }
 }
</script>
```

**Solution**

```js
console.log("Desktop");
if (WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false) {
 document.body.appendChild(WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage());
}
var SEPARATION = 100,
 AMOUNTX = 50,
 AMOUNTY = 50;
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
var particles, count = 0;
var mouseX = 0,
 mouseY = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

// var isMobile = isOSMobile();
var isMobile = true;

init();
animate();

function init() {
 container = document.createElement('div');
 document.body.appendChild(container);
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth /
  window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
 if (isMobile) {
  controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera);
 }
 camera.position.z = 1000;
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 //
 var numParticles = AMOUNTX * AMOUNTY;
 var positions = new Float32Array(numParticles * 3);
 var scales = new Float32Array(numParticles);
 var i = 0,
  j = 0;
 for (var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix++) {
  for (var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy++) {
   positions[i] = ix * SEPARATION - ((AMOUNTX *
    SEPARATION) / 2); // x
   positions[i + 1] = 0; // y
   positions[i + 2] = iy * SEPARATION - ((AMOUNTY *
    SEPARATION) / 2); // z
   scales[j] = 1;
   i += 3;
   j++;
  }
 }
 var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
 geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(
  positions, 3));
 geometry.addAttribute('scale', new THREE.BufferAttribute(scales,
  1));
 var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
   color: {
    value: new THREE.Color(isMobile ? 0xffffff : 0x8D8D8F)
   },
  },
  vertexShader: document.getElementById(
   'vertexshader').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById(
   'fragmentshader').textContent
 });

 particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
 scene.add(particles);

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
 });
 renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove,
  false);
 window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
 if (isMobile) {
  window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
 }
}

function handleOrientation(e) {
 var absolute = e.absolute;
 var alpha = e.alpha;// x -90 ... 90
 var beta = e.beta;// y 180 ... 0
 var gamma = e.gamma;// x -90 ... 90

 mouseX = -5 * windowHalfX * (gamma / 90);
 //mouseY = -windowHalfY * ((beta - 90) / 90);

 // console.log(mouseX.toFixed(2), ' x ', mouseY.toFixed(2));
}

function onWindowResize() {
 windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
 windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
//
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
 mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
 mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
}

//
function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 render();
 if (isMobile) {
  controls.update();
 }
}

function render() {
 camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
 if(isMobile) {
  camera.position.y = 550;
 } else {
  camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * .05;
 }
 camera.lookAt(scene.position);
 var positions = particles.geometry.attributes.position.array;
 var scales = particles.geometry.attributes.scale.array;
 var i = 0,
  j = 0;
 for (var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix++) {
  for (var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy++) {
   positions[i + 1] = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) * 50) +
    (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) * 50);
   scales[j] = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) + 1) * 8 +
    (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) + 1) * 8;
   i += 3;
   j++;
  }
 }
 particles.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
 particles.geometry.attributes.scale.needsUpdate = true;
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 count += 0.1;
}

function isOSMobile() {
 var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

 if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
  return true;
 }
 if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
  return true;
 }

 return false;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The official [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_waves) looks fine on my smartphone. Can you please share your code as a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? Since your code looks like in the example that would make it easier to debug the issue.

Comment: The original code works, however, it does not move when the device moves (accelerometer/gyroscope). I would like to move the waves with motion instead of with touch/mouse move. I tried to mix the waves example and the device controls orientation example but the I get that effect. You can see the error here (liveforevr.webflow.com) Thank you!

Comment: TBH, I'm a bit confused by the provided link. I don't see in your code where you create an instance of `THREE.DeviceOrientationControls`. Besides, it seems you assume that the waves are moved when an interaction is performed. That's wrong since an interaction changes the camera(!) position. In this context it's important to highlight that `DeviceOrientationControls` does only change the rotation of the camera, not its position. So you can't achieve the same behavior of the example by just using `DeviceOrientationControls`.

Comment: I solved it, check update.

Comment: How about to post your solution as an answer and then mark it as solved? This is better than posting your answer within your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Code works, Y axis movement is disabled.

```js
console.log("Desktop");
if (WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() === false) {
 document.body.appendChild(WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage());
}
var SEPARATION = 100,
 AMOUNTX = 50,
 AMOUNTY = 50;
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
var particles, count = 0;
var mouseX = 0,
 mouseY = 0;
var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

// var isMobile = isOSMobile();
var isMobile = true;

init();
animate();

function init() {
 container = document.createElement('div');
 document.body.appendChild(container);
 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth /
  window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
 if (isMobile) {
  controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera);
 }
 camera.position.z = 1000;
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 //
 var numParticles = AMOUNTX * AMOUNTY;
 var positions = new Float32Array(numParticles * 3);
 var scales = new Float32Array(numParticles);
 var i = 0,
  j = 0;
 for (var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix++) {
  for (var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy++) {
   positions[i] = ix * SEPARATION - ((AMOUNTX *
    SEPARATION) / 2); // x
   positions[i + 1] = 0; // y
   positions[i + 2] = iy * SEPARATION - ((AMOUNTY *
    SEPARATION) / 2); // z
   scales[j] = 1;
   i += 3;
   j++;
  }
 }
 var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
 geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(
  positions, 3));
 geometry.addAttribute('scale', new THREE.BufferAttribute(scales,
  1));
 var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
   color: {
    value: new THREE.Color(isMobile ? 0xffffff : 0x8D8D8F)
   },
  },
  vertexShader: document.getElementById(
   'vertexshader').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById(
   'fragmentshader').textContent
 });

 particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
 scene.add(particles);

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
 });
 renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove,
  false);
 window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
 if (isMobile) {
  window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
 }
}

function handleOrientation(e) {
 var absolute = e.absolute;
 var alpha = e.alpha;// x -90 ... 90
 var beta = e.beta;// y 180 ... 0
 var gamma = e.gamma;// x -90 ... 90

 mouseX = -5 * windowHalfX * (gamma / 90);
 //mouseY = -windowHalfY * ((beta - 90) / 90);

 // console.log(mouseX.toFixed(2), ' x ', mouseY.toFixed(2));
}

function onWindowResize() {
 windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
 windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
//
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
 mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
 mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
}

//
function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 render();
 if (isMobile) {
  controls.update();
 }
}

function render() {
 camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
 if(isMobile) {
  camera.position.y = 550;
 } else {
  camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * .05;
 }
 camera.lookAt(scene.position);
 var positions = particles.geometry.attributes.position.array;
 var scales = particles.geometry.attributes.scale.array;
 var i = 0,
  j = 0;
 for (var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix++) {
  for (var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy++) {
   positions[i + 1] = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) * 50) +
    (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) * 50);
   scales[j] = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) + 1) * 8 +
    (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) + 1) * 8;
   i += 3;
   j++;
  }
 }
 particles.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
 particles.geometry.attributes.scale.needsUpdate = true;
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 count += 0.1;
}

function isOSMobile() {
 var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

 if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
  return true;
 }
 if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
  return true;
 }

 return false;
}
```